# forEach() doesn't work properly with my HTML tags, looping over a JSON

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have the following json response from an API, which is saved to `const users` :

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ani",
        "workingHours": {
            "days": {
                "1": {
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "hours": [
                        {
                            "start": "09:00:00",
                            "end": "11:20:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "14:00:00",
                            "end": "17:40:00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "2"
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "hours": [
                        {
                            "start": "09:00:00",
                            "end": "12:30:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "13:00:00",
                            "end": "19:30:00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "3": {
                    "day": "Wednesday",
                    "hours": [
                        {
                            "start": "09:00:00",
                            "end": "12:30:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "14:00:00",
                            "end": "18:30:00"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ben",
        "workingHours": {
            "days": {
                "1": {
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "hours": [
                        {
                            "start": "09:00:00",
                            "end": "12:30:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "14:00:00",
                            "end": "18:30:00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "2": {
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "hours": [
                        {
                            "start": "09:00:00",
                            "end": "12:30:00"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "15:00:00",
                            "end": "18:30:00"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            }
        }
    }]
```

I would like to show in my app the following text for the employees:

```
Ani
Monday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 14:00 - 18:30
Tuesday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 15:00 - 18:30
Wednesday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 14:00 - 18:30 
Ben
Monday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 14:00 - 18:30
Tuesday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 15:00 - 18:30
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript/Typescript?

I'm telling you what I have tried.

```
{users &&
            users.map((user: any) => (
              <p key={user.id}>{user.name}</p> //this is shown correctly
                   {user.workingHours.days.length != 0 &&
                        Object.values(
                          user.workingHours.days
                        ).forEach((entry: any) => (
                          <>
                            <p>{entry.day}</p> 
                            {entry.hours &&
                              entry.hours.map((hour: any) => (
                                <p>
                                  {hour.start} - {hour.end} &&
                                </p>
                              ))}
                          </>
                        ))}

                      
                      )}
```

I know I have implemented it wrong when showing `hour.start` and `hour.end`, but at least I thought I would be able to show correctly `entry.day`. This doesn't happen and I don't really know why, even though I can  log it successfully:

```
{users &&
                users.map((user: any) => (
                 console.log(user.name);
                       {user.workingHours.days.length != 0 &&
                            Object.values(
                              user.workingHours.days
                            ).forEach((entry: any) => (
                              <>
                                console.log(entry.day)                
             ))}
)}
```

Logs:

```
Ani
Monday
Tuesday
Ben
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

It seems like forEach doesn't work with HTML tags at all.

Could someone tell me how to show the following text in my page?

```
Ani
    Monday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 14:00 - 18:30
    Tuesday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 15:00 - 18:30
    Wednesday: 09:00 - 12:30 | 14:00 - 18:30 
    Ben
    Monday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 14:00 - 18:30
    Tuesday: 09:00 - 12:30 && 15:00 - 18:30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `forEach` doesn't return anything, I think you wanted to use `map` for iterating through `Object.values(user.workingHours.days)`.

Comment: I get the error: `user.workingHours.days.map() is not a function`

Comment: Or do you mean : Object.values(user.workingHours.days).map() ?

Comment: @Ani becasue `days` is an object and `map` is not available for objects. - Yes!

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it now. What about hours? How can I show them in the same line with the day, like the text in the question?

Comment: @Ani You did that one correctly, just don't put them into separate `<p>` tags.